# How do I set the Protocol field in an Ipv4 header to 41 in windows?

Tags: ip-address, ipv6, tunnel, tunneling, sockaddr-in

**Background**

For my windows project I create [RFC7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217) ip global unicast addresses. Using [Winsock2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/) and Microsoft's [IpHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/ip-helper-functions) functions these addresses get entered into the PC's local tables, then bind'ed to eventually become listening sockets. From another PC I can connect to these listening end points.

**Problem**

The ISPs do not, however, do Ipv6 very well, if at all. Enter [Hurricane Electric](https://tunnelbroker.net/) with their free tunneling router service complete with /48 prefixes (read: a ton of possible Ipv6 addresses). But I have to get my address end points into their tunnel, programmatically.

**Question**

Which brings me to my question. I can see that a possible solution for my project, is to write encapsulation and decapsulation functions described in [RFC4213](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4213) called [6in4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4). My problem is, however, I haven't figured out how to get my fully formed 6in4 datagram in my [SOCKADDR_IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in) structure so it can be turned into a listening or connecting socket. I don't see header fields like Protocol and Payload Length, which have to be set for the Ipv4 datagram with its Ipv6 contents to work. Maybe there is another set of iphelpers or even more primitive functions that let me set header fields? If so, I haven't found them.

**EDIT1**

Typical config statements for a Hurricane Electric tunnel for Windows:

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel interface=IP6Tunnel localaddress=mmm.mmm.mmm.mmm remoteaddress=216.66.22.2
netsh interface ipv6 add address interface=IP6Tunnel address=2001:jjj:kkk:lll::2
netsh interface ipv6 add route prefix=::/0 interface=IP6Tunnel nexthop=2001:jjj:kkk:lll::1
```

Comment: "_But I have to get my address end points into their tunnel, programmatically._" No. This is a matter of simply configuring your PC. The web site provides sample configurations for many different OSes, including Windows. Do not mess with trying to change packets, simply let it route.

Comment: I have used the scripts. The tunnel is working fine. And I do want to program a particular generated Ipv6 address to onto a typical Ipv4 socket.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are different, incompatible protocols. You simply use routing to route packets from other IPv6 networks to the tunnel. The tunnel simply wraps IPv6 packets with an IPv4 packet. The tunnel is like a physical interface, and you simply route IPv6 packets to it, and it handles the encapsulation for you.

Comment: *...you simply route IPv6 packets to the tunnel and it handles the encapsulation for you* Good news if you say the tunnel does the encapsulation. But how do I feed the tunnel my Ipv6 address? Let's say, to make a listener socket. Currently, I create a valid **SOCKADDR_IN6**, then call **socket->bind->listen**. Ok so far, but if I create a listening socket on Hurricane Electric's **Server IPv4 Address (ie, 216.66.22.2)**, how do I get the target IPv6 structure in there so it will encapsulate it? I don't understand how you would *route* it there.

Comment: You do that by routing. Typically, you would put in a default route (`::/0`) pointing to the tunnel interface, then your IPv6 packets destined for the Internet will travel through the tunnel.

Comment: What makes this more complicated (for good design reasons) for me is, I am creating my own IP SLAAC addresses with random port numbers (RFC7217) and not routing them from some place else. So when you say *physical address*, I am thinking Which HE <ip address>:<port num> goes on the local side? I normally think of this as the *listening* side.

Comment: HE gives you a transit link network, and you assign the `::2` address from that link to your tunnel interface. HE also gives you a `/48` prefix, from which you assign networks for your LAN. I never said physical address, e.g. MAC address, but physical interface. Virtual, e.g. tunnel, and physical interfaces are treated the same. Your IPv4 routing will have a default (`0.0.0.0/0`) IPv4 route pointing at your physical interface. Because you have the IPv6 exit on the tunnel, you put in a default (`::/0`) IPv6 route pointing to the tunnel interface. It is very simple.

Comment: Clear on *physical interface* now. But your discussion only covers routing setup which HE scripts accomplish during tunnel config (see **EDIT1**). You do not address the crucial programming step of how you get and retrieve a created Ipv6 address into the routed interface. How do you create a **socket** followed by a **connect**? The parameters for executing these calls are different for tunnels I suspect. Fx, to create a **socket** you have to know what value to put in **ai_protocol**. Currently I put **IPPROTO_TCP**, but should it be **IPPROTO_IPV6** which has the value of **41**?

Comment: "_How do you create a socket followed by a connect? The parameters for executing these calls are different for tunnels I suspect._" No, as I have been explaining, a tunnel interface is just like a physical interface. "_but should it be IPPROTO_IPV6 which has the value of 41?_" No, that would be for creating automatic 6to4 tunnels, but you have a static 6rd tunnel, so you do not do that. Once you have the routing set up, it is just carrying on as normal, create an IPv4 socket for IPv4 traffic, and create an IPv6 socket for IPv6 traffic. The protocol is the payload of the packet.

Comment: A couple of hours-worth of PowerShell tutorial has gotten me to where I can get/set/remove-netipaddress, With addresses properly set (I used HE's Routed /48) , my RFC7217 implementation, which retrieves the prefix from a router advertisement, is now able to create an Ipv6 address with the proper HE /48 prefix, subnetid and interfaceid, and start listening. Thank you for your guidance.