# ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE for Hurricane Electric's Routed /48 tunnel

Tags: ip-address, ipv6, endpoint, tunnel

**Background**

With the help of this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064005/how-do-i-set-the-protocol-field-in-an-ipv4-header-to-41-in-windows), I am now able to create an Ipv6 listener end point socket. Using **netstat -a -n** here is an example:

```
TCP    [2001:470:5555:57f9:c592:af56:ea9f:9eb1]:50799  [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

This end point is one of 18 octillion possible network end points. For common terminology's sake, here is [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/)'s syntax for an Ipv6 packet:

```
|<----------Global Routing Prefix---------->|<--------Interface------------------------>|
| 001 |<----45 bits---------->|<--16 bits-->|<-----------64 bits----------------------->|
|<--Internet Routing Prefix-->|<-Subnet ID->|<--------Interface ID--------------------->|
```

Hurricane Electric (HE) has thrown us network programmers a lifeline by giving anyone a tunnel. The idea of a tunnel is, anyone can run Ipv6 over today's Ipv4 network and achieve global route-ability, thus circumventing ISPs who don't have (useable) Ipv6. HE's normal *global routing prefix* issued to tunnelers is `2001:470:7:xxxx` where `xxxx` is unique for each tunnel issued. In addition, HE issues a `Routed /48` *internet routing prefix* whose addresses hopefully really are route-able. My *internet routing prefix* is `2001:470:5555` whereas the *subnet ID* and *interface ID* were created by my app using [RFC7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217). `2001` comes from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/) and `470` comes from the HE ISP. This hierarchy of issuers is what makes Ipv6 addresses globally route-able.

**Problem**

And that is the problem: I have not been able to create a routing table that makes my end points globally route-able through Hurricane Electric's tunnel. Fx, for the example test end point above, I get ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE when I try to do a socket connect to it over a tunnel interface (like Hurricane Electric's **IP6Tunnel**).

**Question**

What set of commands (netsh, powershell or win32 ip helper methods) do I need to issue to make my end points globally route-able?

**Attempt 1**

I have not used either Windows *netsh* or *PowerShell* before, but they make it easy to try out various configurations before putting functionality into code. My program creates the end point above. I then have experimented with PowerShell and arrived at these commands:

```
New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 6 -IPAddress 2001:470:5555:: -PrefixLength 48 -DefaultGateway ::/0 // 6 is for the IP6Tunnel interface
New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix 2001:470:5555::/48 -InterfaceIndex 6 -NextHop ::
```

Interfaces and routes are created with the proper *internet routing prefix*, `2001:470:5555`.
But the browser reach-ability test returns only: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

**Edit 2**

Since this is a test of the Hurricane Electric tunnel, then testing using a browser will not work. And instead of *Reachable*, the *Permanent* state is necessary to be connectable. This is because, according to the docs, the *Reachable* state is true if and only if a connection has occurred within the last minute.

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that you should terminate the tunnel on the router, and the pouter should use IPv6 Prefix Delegation to assign the various `/64` internal networks from the `/48` LAN prefix. The router will then send RAs to the hosts for each of the internal networks. This all has nothing to do with programming or code, it has to do with configuring the network. You should really be asking this on [sf].

Comment: Not convinced this problem is a configuration problem. Router RAs are not only generated by configuring routers as you suggest, but by calling networking primitives. Fx, creating the listening end point mentioned above using the RFC7217 standard relies on introducing a generated address into the PC's internal table, which is done by calling `::CreateIpNetEntry2` and then `::ResolveIpNetEntry2`. The former "creates a new neighbor IPaddress entry...". The latter, "...sends neighbor solicitation requests...". The router's response is an RA with the appropriate prefix. No router configuration reqd

Comment: There is another show-stopper problem with the router-configuration approach. Any customer using my app will be dependent on someone setting up his router correctly. Need I mention how many types of routers there are out there? Now compare that to writing a network program using, in this case, Windows ip primitives. The program will work for all routers if done right. Both `netsh` and `PowerShell` are written using these primitives. I want my app to have that same quality. So, it's a no-go for shell scripting. Okay to prototype, but not okay for network app dev.

Comment: "_Any customer using my app will be dependent on someone setting up his router correctly._" That is actually no different than IPv4. The user needs someone to set up a router correctly. In the case of home routers, that happens pretty much automatically for both IPv4 and IPv6. In any case, if you want IPv6 for your network hosts to use to the public Internet, then your router must be configured to route IPv6. Using a tunnel for networks where the ISP does not have IPv6 requires some knowledge about how to configure that on the router for both the transit tunnel and the local IPv6 network(s).

Comment: I was referring to Hurricane Electric's canned tunnel setup scripts as being proper setups. They have one for each OS today. Any router and any ISP works with a `6in4` tunnel since it is wrapping the `ipv6` header and payload in an `ipv4` packet with the Protocol header value set to **41**. This smacks of **RFC4213**. Eventually, I'll be working with HE to eliminate even this manual setup process. Long story as to how that is going to happen.

Comment: Most home routers support the `6rd` that HE uses, but it does take configuration. Configuring an HE tunnel on one of the hosts inside the router really does not work well, except for that particular host. To supply the entire network, you want to configure the router. That is what routers are for, and trying to convert a host on the inside network into a router for IPv6 is less than ideal.